# Chrome menus disappears immediately in 30% cases

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, chromium, menu

In Google Chrome on ubuntu I have a problem: right-click and hamburger menus works fine ~5 times and after that in a ~50% cases they are disappeared immeiately after showing.
Also some dropdowns on some sites doesn't work fine (for example text color selection on google spreadsheets) - they work as if I just clicked on the window below menu.

This problem is fixed by restarting window manager but after 5 clicks it raises again.

What I tried without success:

- updted chrome to last stable version, updated all the packages used
- disabled all chrome extensions
- chromium instead of chrome
- changed ubuntu user
- updated ubuntu version from 20LTS to 22LTS
- used different window managers (lxde, icewm, fluxbox, i3wm, dwm, gnome_on_xorg, unity)

On Firefox those menus work fine.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME Xorg (and Google Chrome version 104.0.5112.101), but I do not have this problem.  [_There are many bugs in Wayland, so still I am still in Xorg!_]  Have you tried disabling any GNOME addons ***and*** Chrome extensions?

Comment: yes (updated the queston), I disabled all chrome extensions.
Also as soon I tried non-gnome window managers, probably none of the Gnome addons were running that time

Comment: also removed add GNOME-* packages

Comment: same problem here. Any progress?

Comment: No progress...  Moreover found same problem on fvwm when number of chrome tabs/windows becomes to be > 10r

Comment: Seems answer about unclutter really catch the source of a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perchance running `unclutter`?  If so, does killing it make this problem go away?  Does for me.  Again this is just a workaround but would help narrow things down.

Comment: YES!! Checked, this was really unclutter. Such a simple solution of a years of pain...

BTW unclutter-xfixes seems to work fine

Answer (score 6):

I am suffering from the exact same problem.
I have only a temporary workaround: when it happens - you can right-click on your desktop, and then come back to the browser.

Unfortunately, it will fix this problem only temporarily, but it is better than nothing.

If anyone finds a better solution I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: What a weird way to fix it. But it works for me on KDE 5.27.4 Tuxedo OS 2 (Ubuntu based)

Comment: Suffering this for years in xmonad and you give me a clue. I move to other workspace and return, and voilá!

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue with drop down menus on Google Chrome (not Chromium) on Kubuntu 22.04 using Xorg not Wayland. At first I thought it was a particular site, or maybe just me, but it was too consistent across several sites.

What has worked for me is changing the Chrome DPI settings, I tested this successfully on at least two of the sites where drop down menus were un-clickable or disappeared etc.

I edited /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop and changed the Exec line like so:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=.96 %U
```

I have personally changed font/DPI settings on my desktop which may also have a bearing on this. So if you've left these settings as default its possible this may not help in your case.

Clearly not ideal but I am suggesting a workaround rather than an answer. I would have added this as a comment, but as a new user I don't have enough reputation!

**P.S. This is my first post here, and I've only just moved from Windows 10 to Kubuntu as my main OS, so please be gentle :)*

Comment: Unfortunatelly this didn't helped me... But thank you for  the answer anyway!